# Atkin sieve algorithm asymptotic analysis

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, sieve-theory

In section 5 in [Atkin sieve paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2004-73-246/S0025-5718-03-01501-1/S0025-5718-03-01501-1.pdf). I don't really understand his analysis of algorithm complexity.

He started with defining $\displaystyle W=12\left(\prod_{3<p\le \sqrt{\log N}}p\right)$ which is roughly $\exp(\sqrt{\log N})$, then he selected $B$ close to $W\sqrt{N}$ (How can we select this step if $WB$ is roughly $N$?, I am not sure about this but the algorithm find primes between $LW$ and $LW+WB$ and the argument he suggested that the number of operations overall $\delta$ is $\mathcal O\left(\dfrac{WB}{\log\log N}\right)$)

Comment: where do you get "$WB$ is roughly $N$" from?

Comment: Around the end of page 1027 and the beginning of page 1028 "The total number of operations over all δ, to compute all the primes between W L
and W L+W B using ϕ1 separate B-bit arrays, is WO(1) +O(ϕ2B/W)+O(ϕ1B) =
O(WB/log log N).
Consequently one can compute all the primes up to N using O(N/log log N)
operations" in the paper. And I didn't get that as I said I am not sure about, but I feel it is by this.